# php get multiple parameters as one

Tags: php, url, get

Im slightly stuck with the get variables for a php script. I want to be able to accept a single url via

> $_GET["url"]

however i have found that if users pass a url like this in

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHP&oq=PHP&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j69i60l2j69i59.3094j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

the script will only read this

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHP

My question is whether there is a way to read the whole url including the other get keys?

Comment: I don't understand....All you do is `$_GET` and you can retrieve that entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not encoding things correctly for use in the URL.  Reserved characters like `&` and `?` must be encoded, or they become ambiguous.

Use `urlencode()`.  That URL becomes:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DPHP%26oq%3DPHP%26aqs%3Dchrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j69i60l2j69i59.3094j0j4%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26es_sm%3D0%26ie%3DUTF-8
```

... which is then safe to use as a value in your query string.